# Take part of the string using bash

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, git-bash

I have string from log file about sending the code like:

```
 <timestamp> INFO   [Response--22] Code [00000000] Code was sent to [+0000002345]
```

Could you help me with parsing it using BASH to put the code value (8chars) to variable?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: could you provide expected output?

Comment: Did you already tried something? Please detail your goal!

Comment: expected output is:
'code =  00000000'

extracted from string "<timestamp> INFO   [Response--22] Code [00000000] Code was sent to [+0000002345]"

Comment: You should edit your question to include the expected output.

Comment: @tripleee funny that the question you refer to is about parsing some XML but yes, it's the same principle.

Comment: @TomFenech I do wish there was better tooling for finding probable duplicates; if you can propose a better duplicate, please do.  There are probably hundreds, but finding a good one is hard work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed to extract the value:

```
sed 's/.*Code *\[\([0-9]*\)].*/\1/' <<<"<timestamp> INFO   [Response--22] Code [00000000] Code was sent to [+0000002345]"
00000000
```

If the line is in a file, you can do `sed '...' filename`. To store the output to a variable, you can do `x=$(sed '...' filename)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly:

```
$ x="<timestamp> INFO   [Response--22] Code [00000000] Code was sent to [+0000002345]"
$ echo "$x" | sed -r 's/.*(Code )\[([0-9]+)\].*/\1= \2/'
Code = 00000000
```

Comment: You should quote `"$x"` when you echo it.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Sorry for dump way of asking.

Comment: @TomFenech : Thanks tom for pointing it out. updated

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/(.*)(Code )\[([0-9]+)\](.*)/code = \3/'
```

**Output:**

```
sdlcb@ubuntu:~/AMD_C$ echo "<timestamp> INFO   [Response--22] Code [00000000] Code was sent to [+0000002345]" | sed -r 's/(.*)(Code )\[([0-9]+)\](.*)/code = \3/'
code = 00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x='<timestamp> INFO   [Response--22] Code [00000000] Code was sent to [+0000002345]'
read -a fields <<<"$x"
code=${fields[4]//[][]/}
echo "code=$code"
```